# How to check another MYSQL join based on a previous join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have the following scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `connections` (
`username1` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`username2` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`username1`,`username2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `connections` (`username1`, `username2`) VALUES
('guy', 'maricela'),
('maricela', 'guy'),
('mikha', 'guy');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`username` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
('maricela', 'Maricela', 'Ros'),
('mikha', 'Michael', 'Samuel'),
('guy', 'Guy', 'Marquez');
```

The scheme contains 2 tables; one for user info called `users` with info first name,last name, and username. The 2nd table is connections. The column `connections.username1` is the one who follows and `connections.username2` is the one who is followed. I want to output a list of the people who follow the user `maricela` and for each result check if the resulting user is followed by the user `mikha` or not.

I use the following query but checking if the result is followed by `mikha` isn't working:

```
SELECT followed_by_mikha.username AS followed_by_mikha,
   users.first_name,
   users.last_name,       
   users.username      
   FROM connections
   LEFT JOIN users ON users.username = connections.username1
   LEFT JOIN users followed_by_mikha ON (connections.username1 = 'mikha' AND connections.username2 = users.username AND connections.username2 = followed_by_mikha.username)
   WHERE connections.username2 = 'maricela'
   ORDER BY users.username DESC LIMIT 10
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT fbm.username2 AS followed_by_mikha,
   users.first_name,
   users.last_name,       
   users.username      
   FROM connections
   LEFT JOIN users ON users.username = connections.username1

   LEFT JOIN connections fbm ON fbm.username2=connections.username1 and fbm.username1 = 'mikha'

   WHERE connections.username2 = 'maricela'
   ORDER BY users.username DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Is there another way to do it without subqueries? I believe subqueries perform slowly on a large scale..thanks

Comment: try the new one; seems working (doesn't check duplicates in connection table)

Comment: I think it's working well :) but what do you mean by it doesn't check for  duplicates?

Comment: if you have two lines ('mikha', 'guy') in connection, you will have two lines in result, although ('guy', 'maricela') is just once; anyway, you can restrict that by defining unique key on two columns in connection table

Comment: I already have a unique key on `username1` and `username2` so `mikha,guy` can't exist twice but `mikha,guy` and `guy,mikha` can both exist..that wouldn't produce duplicates...right?? have another question, do joins perform better than subqueries?? thanks :)